# Meaning of "explosive"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Consider this byline from a magazine article:

> Eleanor McCain and Jeff Melanson were the city’s most influential arts duo—an heiress with deep pockets and powerful friends, and a charismatic executive known as a turnaround king. When their marriage fell apart, the fallout was **explosive**

What does *explosive* mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From it's [definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/explosive?s=t) with reference to your context, the word *explosive* indicates the chaotic sequence of events that followed that *pertains to the nature of an explosion*.

This is a classic news article invitation. By including an ambiguous note at the end, you are attracted to reading more to get clarity of the extract. It even made me to read the news for myself to understand the intended contextual meaning.

Comment: Could you tell me what 'indicate' means in your first sentence? I always been having trouble with this word.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a badly-chosen metaphoric usage, since *by definition*, the literal meaning of [fallout](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fallout) is...

> *Radioactive particles that are carried into the atmosphere after a nuclear explosion and **gradually** fall back as dust or in precipitation*

Most writers obviously agree, noting just 3 written instances of [*fallout was explosive*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22fallout%20was%20explosive%22) in Google Books (compared to 45 [*fallout was **dramatic***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22fallout%20was%20explosive%22#tbm=bks&q=%22fallout%20was%20dramatic%22), 44[*...**huge***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22fallout%20was%20huge%22), 72[*...**intense***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22fallout%20was%20spectacular%22#tbm=bks&q=%22fallout%20was%20intense%22), and 20[*...**spectacular***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22fallout%20was%20spectacular%22), for example).

I'm sure what the writer *means* is that news of the couple's marital breakdown hit the arts community *like a **bombshell / stun grenade*** (they got a sudden, big, and *damaging* shock). But really, I think he's just [getting his metaphors a bit mixed](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mixed-metaphor).